# PHP setcookie() isn't working

Tags: php, cookies

I want to save a cookie that stores whether the client has accepted cookies or not. Currently I have the following code going on.

On the `index.php` page:

```
<?php
    if($_COOKIE["accepted_cookies"] != "true") { // Checks if cookies have been accepted yet, and redirects to cookie page if not
        echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"1; url=https://website.com/php/cookies.php?redirect=https://website.com/\" />";
    }
?>
```

On `/php/cookies.php`

```
<?php 

    $redirect = $_GET['redirect']; //Gets the redirection url from the url
    echo '
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <a href="cookies_accepted.php?redirect='.$redirect.'">Give me cookies!</a>
        </html>'; //Put the accept cookies link on the page

?>
```

On `/php/cookies_accepted.php`

```
<?php

    setcookie("accepted_cookies","true", time()+60); //Sets the accepted_cookies cookie
    $redirect = $_GET['redirect']; //Gets the redirection url from the url

    echo $COOKIE_["accepted_cookies"];
    echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"2; url=".$redirect."\" />"; //Redirects back to the page where the user came from

?>
```

However, the cookie is not actually set and the index keeps redirecting to `/php/cookies.php`. What am I missing?

P.S. The time() in the setcookie function and is temporary and just for testing purposes.

Comment: **HeHeHe** _I want to save a cookie that stores whether the client has accepted cookies or not_ Do you not see the anomily with that statement?

Comment: Is the `$COOKIE_[` bit a typo here or in your real code as well?

Comment: You are in PHP, if you want to redirect to another page [use header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: @RiggsFolly Haha yeah I see it. The cookie is only stored if the client accepts though. I will change the redirect method.

Comment: @GentlemanMax it was. I have fixed it now and moved it to the top of top of the `cookies.php` script. Upon visiting the page it does echo now (as I have accepted the cookies and thus a cookie is stored on my device), but the `index.php` still redirects me. I did some errorhunting and for some reason the cookie seems to not exist for the `index.php`

Answer (score 0):

You should change `$COOKIE_["accepted_cookies"];` in the file `/php/cookies_accepted.php` to be `$_COOKIE["accepted_cookies"];` just like you had it in `index.php`

You can find more information about PHP cookies [here](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php)

Comment: I changed it and moved it to the top of the `cookies.php` script. Upon visiting the page it does echo now (as I have accepted the cookies and thus a cookie is stored on my device), but the `index.php` still redirects me. I did some errorhunting and for some reason the cookie seems to not exist for the `index.php`

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out what the problem was:

The script that stored the cookie was in a subfolder. Because of this, the `index.php` could not acces it. I fixed it by changing the code to `setcookie("accepted_cookies","true", time()+60), "/")`.

Thanks for your responses everyone!